# Add request headers to WebBrowserTask in WP7?

Tags: windows, windows-phone-7, http-headers, httprequest

In the app I'm working on, I want to be able to open the webbrowser and navigate to a specific URL.
This is easy enough using the WebBrowserTask, but the URL I want to reach requires a couple of request headers.

I haven't been able to figure out how to achieve this, and is of course hoping someone here can point me in the right direction, or even show an example.

If the task it self doesn't support headers, is there any other way?

**EDIT:**
Well I found out that the WebBrowserTask in its current state does not support adding headers.
My solution was to make a new XAML page in the app and add a WebBrowser control as the only object. 
The webbrowser control supports adding headers like this:

```
        Uri uri = new Uri("http://YOUR_URL.COM");
        string headers = String.Format("HEADER1:{0}\r\nHEADER2:{1}\r\nHEADER3:{2}\r\n", projectId, username, password);
        webBrowser.Navigate(uri, null, headers);
```

The important part of adding the headers is to remember to seperate the headers with **\r\n**